# Model binding returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying serialize form and binding into model, but some how child of model `InsertToUsertbls` returns `NULL`. Can any help me please :)

I have the following model:

```
public class MangeAddUsers
    {
        public List<InsertToUsertbl> InsertToUsertbls { get; set; }
        public class InsertToUsertbl
        {
            public InsertToUsertbl()
            {

            }

            public int PX2ID { get; set; }
            public string CustomerNR { get; set; }
            public string SellerPersonCode { get; set; }
            public string NameOfCompany { get; set; }
            public string CompanyNo { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

JavaScript to Get data and than load them into form:

```
<script>
    function uuidv4() {
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }

    function myfunction() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Account/GetCustomerContactInfo",
            data: {ids: '10883'},  
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (values) {
                var holderHTML = "";

         for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
             value = values[i]

         if (value != null) {
           var guid = uuidv4();
           holderHTML += '<tr id="row' + value.CustomerNo + '">';
           holderHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="InsertToUsertbls.Index" value="' + guid + '" />';
           holderHTML += '<td><input class="inpt-tbl" type="hidden" id="CustomerNR"  name="InsertToUsertbls[' + guid + '].CustomerNR" value="' + value.CustomerNo + '" /></td>';
           holderHTML += '<td><input class="inpt-tbl" type="hidden"  id="NameOfCompany"  name="InsertToUsertbls[' + guid + '].NameOfCompany" value="' + value.NameOfCompany + '" /></td>';
           holderHTML += '<td><input type="hidden" id="CompanyNo" name="InsertToUsertbls[' + guid + '].CompanyNo" value="' + value.CompanyNo + '" /></td>';
           holderHTML += '<input type="hidden" id="SellerPersonCode" name="InsertToUsertbls[' + guid + '].SellerPersonCode" value="' + value.SalgePersonCode + '" />';
           holderHTML += '</tr>';
                    }
                }

                $('#output').append(holderHTML);
            },

            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        })
    };
</script>
```

And when data load into form:

```
    <form id="mangeUserFrom">
         <div id="output">
           <tr id="row10883">
            <input type="hidden" name="InsertToUsertbls.Index" value="fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec">
            <td>
        <input class="inpt-tbl" type="hidden" id="CustomerNR" name="InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].CustomerNR" value="10883">
            </td>
            <td>
        <input class="inpt-tbl" type="hidden" id="NameOfCompany" name="InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].NameOfCompany" value="Some Name">
            </td>
            <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="CompanyNo" name="InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].CompanyNo" value="849">
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" id="SellerPersonCode" name="InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].SellerPersonCode" value="TT">
           </tr>
            </div>
    </form>
  <button type="button" id="createuser" onclick="PostForm();">POST</button>
```

JavaScript for serializing:

```
<script>
    function PostForm() {

        var formdata = $("#mangeUserFrom").serializeArray();
        console.log(formdata);
        $.ajax({
            "url": '@Url.Action("MangeCreateUsers", "Account")',
            "method": "POST",
            "data": formdata,
            "dataType": "json",
            success: function (data) {


            },

            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }

        });

    }
</script>
```

This is the result of the serialization:

```
{name: "InsertToUsertbls.Index", value: "fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec"}
{name: "InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].CustomerNR", value: "10883"}
{name: "InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].NameOfCompany", value: "Some Name"}
{name: "InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].CompanyNo", value: "849"}
{name: "InsertToUsertbls[fd3424ab-160d-4378-af65-ad2b790812ec].SellerPersonCode", value: "TT"}
```

This is my controller method I'm trying to POST to:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateCustomers(CreateCustomers model)
        {
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Is your controller class annotated with `[ApiController]`? Is your application set-up to expect `CreateCustomers` as a JSON request body or as normal `<form>` values?  What happens if you do a normal (non-AJAX) form post?

Comment: Looks like the way you are building the objcet looks, incorrect, is there any reason why you are using the GUID?

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham just trying binding list like that :)

Comment: I think that may be the issues as your list is expexting [0], [1] and so on, and probably doesn't understand how to parse that into the object you want you may need to steup some custom binding then in your method in order to get ti to work, then maybe pass it as a stingified object, then build your custom method to desrerilize it sever side [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2) may help